# Sequelize returns only one row when using group

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, sequelize.js, node-mysql

When I execute the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `clicks_count`, MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y %m %d')) AS `date`
FROM `listing_clicks`
WHERE (`listing_clicks`.`listing_id` = 24 AND created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y %m %d')
```

in phpmyadmin or using `connection.query()` method I get multiple rows. But when I execute same query using `sequelize.query()` function I get only one row.

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
const daily_clicks = await sequelize.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `clicks_count`, MIN(DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y %m %d')) AS `date`
FROM `listing_clicks`
WHERE (`listing_clicks`.`listing_id` = 24 AND created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y %m %d')", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

Comment: Show your Sequelize code for how you're fetching the row(s).

Comment: @tadman I've updated the question with sequelize code.

Comment: @AmarjitSingh: Paaji can you please update your answer if you get the solution ? I am facing the same issue as yours... Thanks and regards.